# Open file, select sheet and copy it to file with macro

Tags: excel, vba

this is my first post. I would like to have a code which would let user to choose file with filedialog then populate sheet names from the file to userform and copy selected sheet to workbook with the code.

```
Private wbSource As Workbook
Private wsSource As Worksheet

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim I As Long
Dim filedlg As FileDialog

Set filedlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    With filedlg
        .Title = "Please select a file to list Sheets from"
        .InitialFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path
        .ButtonName = "Select"
        If .Show <> -1 Then End
    End With

Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(filedlg.SelectedItems(1))

Me.ComboBox1.Clear
    With wbSource
        For I = 1 To .Worksheets.Count
            Me.ComboBox1.AddItem Sheets(I).Name
        Next
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_Click()

Set wsSource = wbSource.Worksheets(Me.ComboBox1.Value)

wsSource.Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets.Count)
wbSource.Close SaveChanges:=False

Unload Me
End Sub
```

The code is working until excel tries copy the sheet, there is a Run-time error 9 - Subscript out of range. Did I declare variables wrongly?

Comment: I tried in my System, It's working Fine here.

Comment: Maybe Change this `wsSource.Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets.Count)` to `wsSource.Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)`

Comment: Put a dot before Sheets - `Me.ComboBox1.AddItem Sheets(I).Name` to look like `Me.ComboBox1.AddItem .Sheets(I).Name`